# FileChooserBuilder in Netbeans Platform app missing?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

In one of my previous Netbeans Platform apps, I have used this code to bring up a save dialog

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

XMLfile = new org.openide.filesystems.FileChooserBuilder("_output")
                                         .setTitle("Save Dictionary")
                                         .setDefaultWorkingDirectory(home)
                                         .setApproveText("Save")
                                         .setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("xml files (*.xml)", "xml"))
                                         .setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true)
                                         .showSaveDialog();
```

For some reason, in my current Netbeans Platform app, Netbeans IDE cannot find `org.openide.filesystems.FileChooserBuilder` ([javadoc](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems-nb/org/openide/filesystems/FileChooserBuilder.html)). My module declares a dependency on `File System API`, which, as far as I can tell, "imports" the namespace `org.openide.filesystems`.

I could not find any info that `FileChooserBuilder`has been deprecated, neither did I find suggestions for a replacement.

Netbeans IDE suggests to use `javafx.stage.FileChooser` instead, but there I am having troubles with `new javafx.stage.FileChooser.FileChooser().showSaveDialog(Window ownerWindow)` because I do not know how to obtain the `Window` from my `TopComponent`. If I pass `null`, an Exception is thrown (`IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0`), likely because `null` causes a non-modal dialog.

So where has `org.openide.filesystems.FileChooserBuilder`disappeared to, or where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you added the `org.openide.filesystems` JAR library in your project?

Comment: Yes, at least as far as I can tell. By adding a dependency on `File System API` in the module's properties, the corresponding jar file should be added.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it works again. I have removed the dependency on `File System API`, worked on the project for a few days, and added it again. Maybe I have cleared the Netbeans cache (in `%localappdata%`) and the `/build` directories of all modules. Not sure what fixed the problem.